# An attempt to remove the address in a GCP instance failed

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-vpc

I was trying to create a new VM instance and instead of creating a Static External IP, i wrongly created a Static Internal IP. When i do

```
gcloud compute addresses list
```

I get my internal IP listed. Then i use:

```
gcloud compute addresses delete [address-name]
```

It asks for confirmation to delete. But once I type 'Y' as a confirmation, I get the following error stating that the resource itself is not found:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.addresses.delete) Could not fetch resource: - The resource "[MY_RESOURCE_NAME]" was not found
```

I am confused. I hope I am not being charged for this.

Comment: Try to run `gcloud info` and check if your accidentally created IP located in the same region as your default region. In case if regions different you should use flag `--region` with command `gcloud compute addresses delete [address-name]` to avoid such error. If it's not your case, please update your question with full outputs of your commands.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete a static internal IP address from a GCP Instances you could use the following [documentaion](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address#deleting_a_static_internal_ip_address) and do it with the Cloud Console:

1. Go to the VM instances page.
2. Select your project.
3. Select the VM instance from the project list.
4. Select the Edit tool at the top of the page.
5. Click the edit tool for Network Interfaces.
6. Change the Internal IP type from Static to Ephemeral.
7. Select Release to release your static IP address.
8. Click Done to save your changes.

> Your instance continues to use the static IP address until the
>   instance is deleted or restarted. After that occurs, the IP address is
>   returned to the subnet's default pool of available internal IP
>   addresses.